# Mongodb finding a record by native id generated Node.js backend

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-nodejs-driver

First time working with MongoDB. This query works for me in cmd line:

```
db.secrets.update({_id: ObjectId("5f767cd481cea1687b3dbf86")}, {$set: {secret_rating: 5}})
```

However, updating a record using essentially the same query on my node server is not completing this task when pinged. Am I wrong in trying to query for a record like so in my model? ObjectId obviously isn't native to my server.

```
db.secrets.update({_id: "5f767cd481cea1687b3dbf86"}, {$set: {secret_rating: 5}})
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using the [Nodejs Mongodb driver](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/) and not some ORM (since it hasn't been specified), two points of concern:

1. As far as my knowledge serves, if you have a connection object to your desired database in the `db` variable, you cannot reference collections directly such as you've done with `db.secrets`; you must instead use the `collection` method like so:

```js
const secrets = db.collection("secrets");

secrets.find({
    /*your query here*/
}).then((results) => {})
```

So, unless you've assigned `db.secrets` with `db.collection("secrets")` you should be getting an error, `Cannot read property "update" of undefined`. But I'm going to assume you've got the collection object in `db.secrets` since you did not mention you're getting that error.

2. You seem to be using a string instead of an `ObjectID` object. You can import the [ObjectID constructor](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/objectid.html) from the nodejs driver like so:

```js
const ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID
```

Then in your query, you will have to make a new ObjectID to get the correct result:

```js
db.collection("secrets").find({
    _id: new ObjectID("5f767cd481cea1687b3dbf86")
}).then((results) => {})
```

**NOTE:** The `ObjectID` constructor will throw an error if the string supplied to it is not a valid, 24-char hex string, so, if you're getting the `id` string as an input from somewhere (say, as a parameter in an API or as a command line argument), you might want to wrap it in a function that handles that error.